# How can I load the hub.KerasLayer offline?

Tags: tensorflow2.0, keras-layer, h5py, tensorflow-hub

I have build a model by tensorflow hub and save it.
But when I load it, I must add `custom_objects={'KerasLayer':hub.KerasLayer}`.
It will connect the network.

```
model = tf.keras.models.load_model('my_model.h5',custom_objects={'KerasLayer':hub.KerasLayer})
```

How can I download the `hub.KerasLayer` and load it offline?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also use TFHUB_CACHE_DIR to do this automatically

```
import tensorflow_hub as hub
import os

os.environ["TFHUB_CACHE_DIR"] = "/tmp/model"
hub.KerasLayer("https://tfhub.dev/google/nnlm-id-dim50-with-normalization/2")
```

Model assets will be downloaded to /tmp/model/
Future calls to `hub.KerasLayer("https://tfhub.dev/google/nnlm-id-dim50-with-normalization/2")` will use the local copy

Answer (score 2):

In case if you have a downloaded model from TFHub page,

for example,

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_hub as hub

model_path = "path/to/tfhubmodel/"
hub_layer = hub.KerasLayer(hub.load(model_path))
```

Answer (score 0):

Some of it depends if you have a proper saved model. In that case you can just

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_hub as hub


k_layer = hub.KerasLayer("some/file/path")
```

see https://www.tensorflow.org/hub/tf2_saved_model for more details.

Answer (score 0):

The following code can download the model for quickly offline repeated usage. For instance, we choose the keras-io example of tweet-classification-using-tfdf.ipynb.

```
import tensorflow_hub as hub
import tensorflow as tf

module_url = "https://tfhub.dev/google/universal-sentence-encoder/4"
embed = hub.load(module_url)

local_path = "/local/path/directory"
tf.saved_model.save(embed, local_path)

offline_module = hub.KerasLayer(local_path, trainable=True)
```

Please change local_path to your own created path.

Since Google tensorflow_hub every time processes the data in the online method, if users only use the example code as follows,

```
sentence_encoder_layer = hub.KerasLayer(
    "https://tfhub.dev/google/universal-sentence-encoder/4"
)
```

users have to repeated onlinely load the big dataset(about 1GB).

Considering the Internet access speed., URL Error and interruption time to time, the offline loading code shows the extremely high effective and efficient result.

Cheers!